# Special chars (german umlaut) in enum constant

Tags: java, encoding, internationalization, enums

given this enum type:

```
    public enum PackageType  {
    BEHAELTER("BH", "Behälter")

    String value;
    String id;
    String description;

     PackageType(String id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;        
    }
}
```

When working with this enum, the umlaut "ä" in Behälter is shown wrong. Even when i debug in the constructor and watch the attribute "description", i see it wrong.

Is there a Java spec which forbids any special chars in constructs like this? I am pretty clueless at this point.

I noticed that when serializing this enum to JSON and returned it to my frontend.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's nothing to do with enums - you'd probably see the same thing if you just had a console app like this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "Behälter";
    System.out.println((int) x.charAt(3));
  } 
}
```

Possible problems:

- You're not telling the compiler to use the right encoding (this is the most likely option)
- Your debugger isn't capable of showing the value correctly
- Your JSON serialization isn't working properly (e.g. you're not sending the right encoding)
- Your JSON *deserialization* isn't working properly (e.g. the frontend is ignoring the encoding you're specifying)

The first option is the most likely, to be honest. If that's the case, it's easy to test - change the string to `"Beh\u00e4lter"` - the character you're interested in is U+00E4, so that Unicode escape allows you to express it in a string literal without going outside ASCII in the actual source code.

If that does indeed work, then you could go back to the previous code but check how your source file is actually being saved, and what your compiler options say. (Personally I'd recommend using UTF-8 as a full-Unicode, well-supported encoding.)

Comment: Sorry, but i cant confirm that. I am developing apps with this IDE settings since ages and i ve never had problems with the debugger or the encoding of the java files.
All of my java files are in UTF-8 and my IDE knows that its UTF-8. 
When i run your simple program, the debugger and also the commandline show the right thing, i.e. the "ä". 

Its not a "general" problem and of course its not related to JSON, since the strings is "broken" before the serialization happens.

Comment: But now within that main method, i used the enum and there everything is fine. So i need to recheck the current business case why it fails there. So perhaps your answer helps me anyway. Will promote it as soon as i checked some things.

Comment: @Marc: You say "of course" but we've no idea what you've already tried. Okay, so it sounds like it isn't the compiler... if you print out the character at index 3 in the debugger, what's it showing? Can you give a similar short but complete program to show it failing? If you believe it has nothing to do with JSON, then you shouldn't need to worry about the JSON side of things. When you say it's "shown wrong", what *exactly* are you seeing? It's hard to help you further without more information.

Comment: I tried it now for a few days. Everything is fine as if the problem has never been existed in the first place. This is annoying but it looks like a system or IDE weirdness. But your answer was helpful anyway.